# trying to pass one page data to next page but unfortunately data is not displayed

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

i am working in Django quiz project i am trying to display the answer the next page but using question.html user can select answer and click submit then next page is displayed but marks is not displayed i am use java-script to displayed marks...  how can we solve the problem ??

**question.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>


    {% load static %}

    <script src="{% static 'JS/quiz1.js' %}"></script>


</head>
<body>



    <div id = "txt"></div>
    <form name="quizform"  action="{% url 'answer' %}" method="POST"  onsubmit="return submitanswer(answers=[{% for poll in questions %}'{{ poll.right_ans }}', {% endfor %}])">
        {% csrf_token %}



    {% for poll in questions %}
        <h1>{{poll.question_id}}{{poll.question}}</h1> 
        <h3><input type="radio" name="poll{{poll.question_id}}" id="poll1a" value="{{poll.option_1}}"  >a.{{poll.option_1}}</h3>
        <h3><input type="radio" name="poll{{poll.question_id}}" id="poll1b" value="{{poll.option_2}}">b.{{poll.option_2}}</h3>
        <h3><input type="radio" name="poll{{poll.question_id}}" id="poll1c" value="{{poll.option_3}}">c.{{poll.option_3}}</h3>

        <h3><input type="radio" name="poll{{poll.question_id}}" id="poll1d" value="{{poll.option_4}}" >d.{{poll.option_4}}</h3>
    {% endfor %}

    <input type="Submit" value="Submit Answer" onclick="passvalues();" >
    </form>


</body>
</html>
```

**answers.html**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>Result</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    document.getElementById('maitrik').innerHTML=localStorage.getItem('textvalue');

 </script>
</head>
<body>


 congretulations!.. <span id="maitrik">Hello</span>

</body>
</html>
```

**quiz1.js**

```
function submitanswer(answers)
{
    var total = answers.length;
    var score = 0;
    var choice=[]


    for(var i=1;i<=total;i++)
    {
        choice[i]=document.forms["quizform"]["poll"+i].value;
    }



    for(i=1;i<=total;i++)
    {
        if(choice[i]== null || choice[i] == ''){
                alert('you missed questions:'+i);
                return false;
            }
    }



            //var right_answer=["a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a"]
    for(i=1;i<=total;i++)
    {
        if(choice[i] ==answers[i-1]){
            score=score+1;


        }
        console.log(answers[i]);
    }


    var results=document.getElementById('results');
    results.innerHTML="<h3>Your scored is <span>" + score + "</span>  out of <span>"+total +"</span></h3>"
    alert("You scored" + score + "out of" +total);
    return false;



}

function passvalues()
{
 var firstname=document.getElementById("txt").value;
 localStorage.setItem("textvalue",firstname);
 return false;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Are you doing any processing in views.py when clicking on this submit answer? Can you post the method definition corresponding to answer in views.py? Also, just to confirm, is this line being displayed in the next page? --> congretulations!.. <span id="maitrik">Hello</span>

Answer (score 0):

There are few mistakes in your code.

In **answers.html** you have to mention the script part at the end(Not in the `<head>`). Otherwise the script will get executed first and you will get a null when you get the item from localStorage.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

        <title>Result</title>

    </head>
    <body>


     congretulations!.. <span id="maitrik">Hello</span>

    </body>
    </html>

<script type="text/javascript">

        document.getElementById('maitrik').innerHTML=localStorage.getItem('textvalue');

     </script>
```

And then you haven't made a tag with id ='results' for printing the marks. Once that's done you will get the expected result.

Thank you.